# How can I solve this variable-coefficient ODE system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, systems-of-equations

I originally have a linear, homogeneous, second-order variable coefficient ODE system of this form:

$X''(x) = A(x)X(x)$, where

$X(x) = $\begin{bmatrix}
f(x)        \\
g(x)        \\
\end{bmatrix}

and

$A(x) = $\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\lambda+\alpha}{x(1-x)} & -\frac{\lambda}{x(1-x)}        \\
-p^2 & p^2        \\
\end{bmatrix}

So far, I've tried to reduce this system to the normal form shown below, but without any particular success.

$X'(x) = A(x)X(x)$, where

$X(x) = $\begin{bmatrix}
f_1(x)        \\
f_2(x)        \\
g_1(x)  \\
g_2(x)
\end{bmatrix}

and

$A(x) = $\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\  \frac{\lambda+\alpha}{x(1-x)} &0& -\frac{\lambda}{x(1-x)} & 0        \\  0&0&0&1\\
-p^2 &0& p^2 & 0      \\
\end{bmatrix}

I know that this broadly lies under the theory of time-varying systems, but have little idea how to go about looking for exact analytical solutions.

Thank you!

Comment: Indeed, if $X(x)=\begin{bmatrix}u(x)\\ v(x)\end{bmatrix}$ and $X''(x)=A(x)X(x)$ with $A(x)=\begin{bmatrix}a(x)&b(x)\\ c(x)&d(x)\end{bmatrix}$ then $Y'(x)=B(x)Y(x)$ where $Y(x)=\begin{bmatrix}u'(x)\\ u(x)\\ v'(x)\\ v(x)\end{bmatrix}$ and $B(x)=\begin{bmatrix}0&a(x)&0&b(x)\\ 1&0&0&0\\ 0&c(x)&0&d(x)\\ 0&0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$. Is this your question?

Comment: Hi @Did, I want to be able to find analytical solutions of that system. What you have mentioned is a transformation I've used in the hope of getting to the solution.

Comment: Thanks @Did, for your prompt response. From my understanding, that works only when B commutes with itself at different times (which is not true for my case).

Ref:
1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_expansion
2. http://www.me.umn.edu/courses/me8281/Lectures/Lectures3.pdf

Comment: Alright. Do you have any suggestions, though, for my particular problem, then?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1322586/